# C++ While loop not working correctly

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am using the following code to break apart a line of text.

A line of text, such as 
"adduser john -u 2001 -g 1002 -p john123 -c Project Work"
is passed to the constructor.

I am trying to separate the text by the commands "-u, -g, -p, -c"

"john" will be saved as name,
"2001" will be saved as UID,
"1002" will be saved as GID, etc.

```
AccountInfo::AccountInfo(char* line){
_line = line;
char bufferLine[256];
unsigned int length1 = 0;
unsigned int tempLength1 = 0;

//find length of line of text
while (_line[length1] != '\0'){
    length1++;
}
//separate the text by white space
// start at 8 because adduser is not a command
for (int i = 8; i < length1 + 1; i++){
    bufferLine[tempLength1 + 1] = '\0';
    printf(bufferLine);
    if (_line[i] == ' ')
    {

        if (bufferLine[0] == '-')
        {
            //test only u and c commands for now
            if (bufferLine[1] == 'u'){


                bufferLine[0] = '\0'; //clear contents of array
                tempLength1 = 0;

                while (!_line[i] == '-'){
                    bufferLine[tempLength1] = _line[i];
                    i++;
                    tempLength1++;
                }
                bufferLine[tempLength1] = '\0';
                printf(bufferLine);
                printf("\n This is UID \n");
                setUID((unsigned int)bufferLine);
            }

            else if (bufferLine[1] == 'c'){

                bufferLine[0] = '\0';
                tempLength1 = 0;

                while (!_line[i] == '\0'){
                    bufferLine[tempLength1] = _line[i];
                    i++;
                    tempLength1++;
                }

                bufferLine[tempLength1] = '\0';
                printf(bufferLine);
                printf("\n this is gecos \n");
                setGecos(bufferLine);
            }

        }

        else{
            //is name
            bufferLine[tempLength1] = '\0';
            setName(bufferLine);
            printf("\n I am the user's name\n");
            printf(bufferLine);
            printf("\n");

        }
        bufferLine[0] = '\0'; //reset buffer line
        tempLength1 = 0; // reset incrementation for buffer line

    }

    else{
        bufferLine[tempLength1] = _line[i];
        tempLength1++;
    }
}
}
```

I am working on functionality of the -u command. It reaches the 
if (bufferLine[1] == 'u') portion of the code, but always bypasses the while loop following it
while (!_line[i] == '-')          I have tried changing the '-' to exit the while loop with ' ' and even any letter 'a' 'g' 'd', however nothing works except '\0'. This is only acceptable for the -c command, as everything after it should be printed.

The -c command works as it should, as does saving the name. However, none of the other commands will work because it does not make it to the loop.

I have been thinking about this problem for a while and I believe it should work, however the code never makes it through the while loop. Is there a problem with the syntax? Or is there something I am missing about nested loops?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression

```
while (!_line[i] == '-'){
```

evaluates as (see [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)):

```
while ((!(_line[i])) == '-') { // because ! has higher precedence than ==
while (false == '-') {         // because _line[i] == ' ', !' ' is false
while (false) {
```

You probably meant

```
while (_line[i] != '-') {
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm new to C++ and never imagined precedence to be the reason for it working. However, now I'm getting an Unhandled exception. It is saying <Error reading characters of string> when it gets to -p

Answer (score 0):

`while (!_line[i] == '-')` is essentially `while ((!_line[i]) == '-')` (note the [operators precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)).

What you possibly want is `while (! (_line[i] == '-')) {` or, simpler, `while (_line[i] != '-'){`.

Answer (score 0):

```
!_line[i] == '-'
```

`!` has lower precedence than `==` and is evaluated as

```
(!_line[i]) == '-'
```

and this will never be true

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence